# ¿Cómo agregar una tabla despues de un bookmark con c#?

Tags: c#, .net

Hola amigos estoy trabajando en un proyecto en donde debo de crear una serie de documentos en base a una plantilla, dichos documentos tienen MergeFields los cuales debo reemplazar por código en base a un dataset, dichos valores ya se reemplazan correctamente y se generan bien los N documentos. El problema que tengo es que necesito agregar en cada documento una tabla con N valores y columnas en base a una consulta, e intentado el siguiente código pero no funciona, al parecer no me reconoce el marcador que puse, ya que al parecer en el ejemplo la tabla se agregaría después de dicho marcador. Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    object objMiss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    object objEndOfDocFlag = "\\tabla";
    Word.Range objWordRng = oWordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objEndOfDocFlag).Range;

    Word.Table objTab1 = oWordDoc.Tables.Add(objWordRng, dt.Rows.Count, NumCols,ref objMiss, ref objMiss);
    objTab1.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6;

    int iRow, iCols;
    for (iRow = 1; iRow <= dt.Rows.Count; iRow++)
    {
        for (iCols = 1; iCols <= NumCols; iCols++)
        {
            objTab1.Cell(iRow, iCols).Range.Text = dt.Rows[iRow][iCols].ToString(); //add some text to cell
        }
     }  
 }
```

El error que me marca es el siguiente: ***El elemento del conjunto solicitado no existe.*** Al parecer se refiere al marcador, ya que cuando lo ejecute paso a paso el código entro al catch en esa parte. 
Les agradecería mucho me pudieran apoyar en como solucionar este detalle o si hay alguna otra forma de agregar una tabla.

Comment: cual sería "esa parte" ?

Comment: En donde me marca el error es en esta linea Word.Range objWordRng = oWordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objEndOfDocFlag).Range;

Comment: Al parecer por lo que ví no logra encontrar el marcador que agregue a mi plantilla de Word

Comment: o quizás el problema esté al agregar el marcador. ¿lo agregas por código?

Comment: No el marcador esta en la plantilla de word que estoy usando para generar mi reporte, como comente en la pregunta ya logre reemplazar los MergeFields del principio del documento pero después de esos campos viene la creación de la tabla para completar el reporte.

Comment: Analiza en paso a paso, que contiene oWordDoc.Bookmarks , quizás eso te  pueda indicar si existe un item \\tabla

Comment: Ya quedo resuelto, al parecer estaba introduciendo mal el marcador, gracias por tu consejo. Se puede marcar como resuelta la pregunta y como seria? es que soy nuevo relativamente

Comment: Puedes agregar una respuesta con la solucion a tu problema, y en 2 días te da la opcion de aceptar tu propia respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Ya quedo resuelto, al parecer estaba introduciendo mal el nombre del marcador en vez de **\tabla** no me lo aceptaba así que intente con **tabla** y funciono correctamente.